# WPF Binding to plain property - not working

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a control where I want to bind a colour to plain property in its own class.

But it fails to work ??? any Clues ?

I have this

```
 public Brush SeperatorColour
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(SeperatorColourProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SeperatorColourProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SeperatorColour.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SeperatorColourProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SeperatorColour", typeof(Brush), typeof(TycoMessageBarMessage), new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Crimson));
```

And this

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black" >
    <Rectangle Name="MessageSeperator" Height="auto" Width="10" Fill="{Binding Path=SeperatorColour, ElementName=container, Mode=OneTime}"   />
    <TextBlock Name="MessageText" Text="Hello"  Foreground="White" Margin="5,0" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Hope you are setting the DataContext

Comment: Look in the Output window inside Visual Studio under debug. There should be binding errors.

Comment: One of those questions that could easily be solved by understanding the basics first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ElementName=container

implies that you are binding to another XAML element named 'container', you will probably want to bind to some instance of the object with the 'SeperatorColour' property.

If you're not binding to another XAML element, do not add "ElementName" to the binding expression.

Comment: I have removed the "ElementName" - still no joy

Comment: Do I need to set the data binding to "this" somehow ?

Comment: The data context is of importance here.

Comment: By default, the data context is 'this'.
You can set the data context from code-behind using `object.DataContext = otherObject;`
or from XAML (to reference another XAML object) using `Datacontext="otherObject"`

Answer (score 1):

You either need to set the name of your control to `container`:

```
<UserControl xmlns="..."
             x:Name="container">
```

OR use relative binding:

```
Fill="{Binding Path=SeperatorColour, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MyControl}}, Mode=OneTime}"
```

Here, instead of `MyControl` you need to specify type of your control.

In case if it is a custom control and the XAML you've shown is located inside a control template for the control, then you can use `TemplateBinding`:

```
Fill="{TemplateBinding SeperatorColour}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfectly, if you have correctly set the DataContext for your UserControl -

```
 <Rectangle Name="MessageSeperator" Height="auto" Width="10" Fill="{Binding Path=SeperatorColour, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"   />
```

What do you see in Output window on running you application? Was there any data binding error??

To debug your data bindings, please refer - http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/index.php?s=presentationtrace